# Change subtitle using CastPlayer

Tags: android, chromecast, exoplayer

I do have a HLS livestream which is epresented by an URI pointing to the manifest file.
The manifest file does additionally define the subtitles.

When using the ExoPlayer I can use a TrackSelector, attach it to the ExoPlayer and so I do have the option to show the available subtitles to the user (and change it through the TrackSelector).

I want to do the same with just the CastPlayer. Here the simplest possible Activity I can imagine:

```
 public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SessionAvailabilityListener {

    private MediaRouteButton castButton;
    private CastPlayer castPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player_activity);

        castButton = findViewById(R.id.castButton);
        CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(this, castButton);

        CastContext castContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this);
        castPlayer = new CastPlayer(castContext);
        castPlayer.setSessionAvailabilityListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCastSessionAvailable() {
        MediaMetadata movieMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);

        MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder("https://myuri.ch/video.m3u8")
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
                .build();

        MediaQueueItem mediaItem = new MediaQueueItem.Builder(mediaInfo).build();
        castPlayer.loadItems(new MediaQueueItem[]{mediaItem}, 0, 0, Player.REPEAT_MODE_OFF);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCastSessionUnavailable() {
    }
}
```

The layout looks like this:

```
    <androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton
            android:id="@+id/castButton"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton>
```

This activity starts up and when I hit the castButton it streams the movie behind "https://myuri.ch/video.m3u8" to the cast-device. Works perfectly :)

But I can't figure out how to allow the user to choose between subtitles from my app. What is the idea on how we should implement something like this?

Points I already found out:

- I cannot attach something like a TrackSelector to the CastPlayer
- The docuentation states that we can provide MediaTracks to the MediaInfo-Object. But I dont have this info, respectively it is hidden in the m3u8 file.

As additional info, my CastOptions look like this:

```
public class CastOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {
    @Override
    public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context appContext) {

        return new CastOptions.Builder()
                .setReceiverApplicationId(CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here what I found out:

1. The TrackSelector cannot be used for the CastPlayer.
2. Alle the available subtitles have to be available/known before you load MediaItems to the CastPlayer
3. The DefaultMediaReceiver needs a public available link to a *.vtt file. Something different does not work (no .webvtt nor .m3u8)
4. The easiest way to update the subtitles on the ExoPlayer seems to be this:

```
        DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder parametersBuilder = trackSelector.getParameters()
                .buildUpon()
                .setRendererDisabled(getRendererIndex(C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT), !hasSubtitles);

        if (hasSubtitles) {
            parametersBuilder.setPreferredTextLanguage("en").build();
        }
```

Where getRendererIndex is this:

```
    public int getRendererIndex(final int trackType) {
        for (int t = 0; t < exoPlayer.getRendererCount(); t++) {
            if (exoPlayer.getRendererType(t) == trackType) {
                return t;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

5. To select a SubTitle on the CastPlayer you can use the RemoteMediaClient

```
remoteMediaClient.setActiveMediaTracks(selectedSubtitleTracks);
```

So my solution is this:

1. Before starting any stream (local or cast) get all the information I need for the MediaItem (url, subtitles, ...)
2. Depending on the availability of a Cast-Session I load the MediaItems to the CastPlayer or the ExoPlayer
3. A Custom subtitle-dialog gives the user the option to select a subtitle
4. When the user selects a subtitle, I use the methods described above to select the subtitle on the correct player.

Comment: is there any way can you make a github file on above answer